# How can I capture a screenshot of an entire webpage in iPhone's Safari browser?

Tags: software-recommendation, iphone, screen-capture, mobile-safari

How to capture screenshot of entire webpage in iPhone's Safari browser like I can take in my Desktop with Help of Firefox Addon called [Fireshot](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/fireshot/)? 
[image: Fireshot screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching a lot on this thing finally I got the solution.
[Website Screenshot](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/website-screenshot/id437683442?mt=8#) worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Not available in US Store.

Answer (score 1):

Nuc's answer would give you a screen shot that renders accurately but would not show the Safari chrome but with very little work.

Another more difficult option would be to take multiple screenshots by pressing wake+home, scrolling in between so that there is a small overlap between shots.  You could then offload them onto a PC/Mac and then composite them together.  The benefit is you would get the full Safari UI showing.

Comment: I've bought Cinder and iScreenshot both but don't know how to get full page screenshot

Answer (score 1):

I use [PixiWeb](https://itunes.apple.com/app/pixiweb-capture-webpage-screenshot/id565100962) to capture website screenshots in its entirety or only visible area.

It also allows saving screenshots as PDF. Sharing options are quite impressive too (most social media sites).

Answer (score 0):

Although not free, you may get websnaps using [Cinder](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cinder/id346434241?mt=8) (ex. LittleSnapper)

Answer (score 0):

Try [iScreenshot](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/iscreenshots/id417162696?mt=8)

Comment: How to use this? I've installed

Comment: Thanks for your answer, tool! Can you please add more information about the software you linked to? How does it answer the OP's question. Answers on Ask Different are expected to be more than a link, and need to give a specific answer to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Webpage Capture](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/webpage-capture/id348797820?mt=8) ($1.99) for iPhone/iPad. It promises

> "to take a screenshot of the complete webpage you are browsing"

and also saves to PDF.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Najm! Can you please add more information about the software you linked to? How does it answer the OP's question. Answers on Ask Different are expected to be more than a link, and need to give a specific answer to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Other options include:

[Barry](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/barry-webpage-screenshot/id588626031?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo=4&affId=1503186)

Solves this problem by generating a screenshot of the entire page. All you have to do is open up a webpage in Barry's built-in browser and hit Capture. It'll save a full-length screenshot to an in-app camera roll where you can export it to your **main camera roll**, **Dropbox**, **an email**, **a Tweet**, or your **clipboard**.

The developers also included a useful **Safari bookmarklet** that sends your current page straight to the app so you won't have to copy the URL and dig around your home screen to find it.

The other alternative you could do, is to access the mobile version of the website concerned, resize the window to match that of your iPhone window and use the extension to take the screenshot.

Answer (score -3):

I'm the developer of [Scissors](https://appsto.re/us/RBcveb.i). It allows you to select and clip the whole page or any part of the page
even if the selected part of the page is beyond the bounds of the screen.

It's an action extension, so you can launch it from any web browsers.
It has a designated clipping tool like evernote web clipper desktop version.

Comment: Please read the part about self-promotion in https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/behavior.